# how do I call a function in a function in onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to call my function in a function
it looks like that:
(js)

```
function ingadd (){
 \\code
  function recpag (){
    \\code}
now how do I call recpag in onclick(html)
I tried like a regular function but it didn't work..
 thank you ♡♡
```

Comment: OP , try posting text content out of the coding block and be a little descriptive of your question and effort you've put so far. Be a little formal if you could , happy learning .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it appears you are new to javascript. There are a lot of online resources on javascript fundamentals, and those places will probably provide more benefits for a beginner.

I googled a random one:
https://javascript.info/function-basics#functions-comments

In that section, the code sample uses a "isPrime" function within a "showPrimes" function.